# I try using SymPy in Julia 1.7.1 and get "coeffs not found" error

Tags: python, julia

I am trying to use coeffs function in Julia 1.7.1 but getting the error below:

[image: i get error while using [p0].coeffs().keys()]

the error occurs in the below code in the last line where i have  `S = [p0].coeffs().keys()` see the code below:

```
p0 = sympify(dense_interpolation([a[1]] .+ r, [p0] .+ P).subs(Symbol('x'), x_var[1]))
print("[p0] = ")
println([p0])
print("p0 = ")
println(p0)
S = [p0].coeffs().keys()
```

the type of the `p0` is `Sym` and the value inside it is `1` as you can see on the first picture.
can anyone help me out on this.

Comment: deleted.........

Comment: Why are you doing `[p0].coeffs()`?  I think you just want `p0.coeffs()`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo this is using Julia's PyCall bindings to interface with SymPy.  It does relate to Python.

Comment: i tried it , i get the same error.

Comment: @AshrafYawar can you please replace the images of code with text?  And structure the code such that others can replicate your issue?

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . What is `a` what is `r` etc. It is quite hard to help with a piece of code cut out from the context.

Comment: a and r, those are just to have an idea about that P0 contains, since we only need to know the type of p0 and the value it contains.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the latest doc build, but search for coeffs here https://docs.juliahub.com/SymPy/KzewI/1.1.1/introduction/

One thing, [p].coeffs is very unlikely to work, as this doesn’t call the method of p, rather a container you created with [].